# Given ideal $I \subset$ $ \mathbb{R}[X]$ contains the polynomials $X^2 + 1$ and $X^5+X+1$ show that $I =\mathbb R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose that $R = \Bbb{R}[X]$ with the usual addition and multiplication of polynomials as ring operators. Further suppose that an ideal $I \subset$ $ \mathbb{R}[X]$ contains the polynomials $X^2 + 1$ and $X^5+X+1$. Show that $I=\Bbb{R}[X]$.

answer:
We already know that $I \subset  \mathbb{R}[X]$; the equality $ I= \mathbb{R}[X]$ can be proved by double inclusion.
The polynomials $X^2+1$,$X^5+X+1 \in I$ and since $I$ is an ideal:

$$r \in \mathbb{R}[X] \Rightarrow r(X^2+1) \in I $$
$$s \in \mathbb{R}[X] \Rightarrow s(X^5+X+1) \in I $$

According to the extended Euclidean algorithm, one can find polynomials $r$ and $s$ such that :

$$r\cdot(X^2+1) + s\cdot (X^5+X+1) = \text{gcd}(X^2+1,X^5+X+1)=1 $$

that is as well an element of $I$ because of the closed property of an ideal ring.

$\forall f(x)\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ we have that $f(x) \cdot 1 \in I$ it follows that : $f(x) \in I$. So we can conclude that $\mathbb{R}[X] \subset I$.

Comment: Is the $R$ in the first sentence an arbitrary ring, or is it that $\Bbb{R}$ and you made a typo?

Comment: I see now what you meant, so you can ignore my last comment (although you should update your post). You may need some justification that $\gcd(X^2+1,X^5+X+1)=1$, but the idea is correct. I would personally just find explicit $r,s$ which give you $1$; it's not too difficult and much more concrete. I'll post an answer detailing how I'd write it.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Stahl I think he just wants to know if his proof is valid.

Comment: Thank you Alex.
Stahl I was just wondering if I was on the right direction with my answer.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, your proof should be okay, barring some stubbornness from a grader about how obvious it is that $\gcd(X^2+1,X^5+X+1)=1$. Here is another approach that amounts to the same thing:

Since $I$ is an ideal containing $X^2+1$ and $X^5+X+1$, we have

$$1=(X^5+X+1)-(X^3+X)(X^2+1)\in I$$

which as you've noted implies $I=\Bbb{R}[X]$.